# App not installed error during development process

Tags: java, android

My app is working fine on my phone which i use for development. But as I am using the app on any other phone I does not install with an error of 'App Not Installed'.

Comment: To get an answer you have to supply more information like, logcat, any exceptions, screenshots mm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a release version of the app or you can also try creating a signed-release version of the app. 
Reffer to this documentation from Google [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a release version of the app or you can also try creating a signed-release version of the app.
Check this link out 
It has good documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html
Sign Your App | Android Studio - Android Developers